# Error in running eclipse : Error initializing storage due to java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, rhel5

I was using Eclipse and everything was okay but suddenly, I couldnt open my eclipse in Linux (RHEL). I also already uninstalled and reinstalled the eclipse but the error is still there.

here is the log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing storage.
>    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.
>    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.(Equinox.java:31)
>    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:303)
>    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
>    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
>    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
>    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472) Caused by: java.io.EOFException
>    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
>    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.loadGenerations(Storage.java:1160)
>    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.(Storage.java:137)
>    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:85)
>    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.
>     ... 11 more

Things already tried :

delete the org.eclipse.osgi under configuration files (Not fix the problem)

Update :

under {workspace}/./metadata/.log

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to open archive: /home/***/tracecompass-incubator-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.eclipse$
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.model.ApiElement.abort(ApiElement.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.model.ArchiveApiTypeContainer$ArchiveApiTypeRoot.getContents(ArchiveApiTypeContainer.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.model.AbstractApiTypeRoot.getStructure(AbstractApiTypeRoot.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.provisional.comparator.ApiComparator$2.visit(ApiComparator.java:662)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.model.ArchiveApiTypeContainer.accept(ArchiveApiTypeContainer.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.provisional.comparator.ApiComparator.internalCompare(ApiComparator.java:656)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.provisional.comparator.ApiComparator.compare(ApiComparator.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.provisional.comparator.ApiComparator.compare(ApiComparator.java:312)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.builder.BaseApiAnalyzer.checkCompatibility(BaseApiAnalyzer.java:1421)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.builder.BaseApiAnalyzer.analyzeComponent(BaseApiAnalyzer.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.builder.ApiAnalysisBuilder.buildAll(ApiAnalysisBuilder.java:757)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.builder.ApiAnalysisBuilder.build(ApiAnalysisBuilder.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/****/tracecompass-incubator-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.c$
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.internal.model.ArchiveApiTypeContainer$ArchiveApiTypeRoot.getContents(ArchiveApiTypeContainer.java:103)
        ... 22 more
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you looked for other exceptions into `{workspace}/.metadata/.log`?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I already add the log in the question. Thanks. I really appreaciate your help

Comment: Try reinstalling the tracecompass plugin.